# C#/.NET string magic to remove comment lines from text file input?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

Say you have a text file you read in as a long string:

```
123 123 123
123 123 123
// Just a comment
123 123 123    
123 123 123
# Just a comment
123 123 123
```

You typically split it in to lines something like this, (example in Unity3D),

```
    List<string> lines = new List<string>(
        controlFile.text.Split(new string[] { "\r","\n" }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

.NET offers an incredible amount of string magic, such as formatting and more.

I wonder, is there some **available magic** to easily remove comments?

NOTE - of course one can do this using a regex, etc. As SonerGönül points out it can usefully be done with `.Where` and `.StartsWith`

My question, is there some facility in the universe of .NET string magic, **which specifically "understands" and helps with comments**.

Even if the answer from an expert is "definitely no" that's a useful answer.

Comment: The issue is every format uses a different delimiter for comments. So the method would need to be parameterized to accept your type of comment delimiter. And in your example, you have two shown. Are there more possibilities? Or just those two?

Comment: What are the possibilities of a comment lines? Only starts with `//` or `#`? If so, you can use something like `.Where(line => !line.StartsWith("//") || !line.StartsWith("#"))` maybe?

Comment: Another important question is do you need to support *inline* comments, or can we assume that the comment is at the beginning of the line, and the entire line can be removed?

Comment: `lines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("//"))`

Comment: Are you asking about the parsing into lines, or the removal of comments once you have a bunch of lines? (Or both?)

Comment: You mean something along the lines of getting the compiler's parser to remove the comments for your?  I have no idea, but that would be cool.

Comment: Hi Cody -- indeed, .Net "magic" usually completely handles such situations.  (Consider the incredible power of text formatting for different monetary systems, times, regional displays etc.)  I'm surprised there isn't just something like "String.RemoveComments.(c-style)" or whatever with different options.

Comment: Hi enig and soner -- I guess, that is really the best answer.  I'm somewhat surprised this is not "built-in" to .Net, considering how much other incredible magic is available in .Net for string handling

Comment: @JoeBlow I think it's a bit naive to think that the built-in `String` type would  support "magic" for such things.  The "magic" stuff you're referring to is almost entirely related to the locale of the machine.  Expecting it to have magic to natively support your custom file-format is asking a bit much, I think.

Comment: Hi Joshua, hmm, to me it seems like the most obvious thing in the world.  **Every single time, ever** that you read in a text file, you remove blank lines (of course there's a built-in way to easily do that) and you remove obvious comment lines!  Anyways, I just wanted to know from someone really familiar with .Net (not me!! :) ) if there was such a thing.

Comment: heh @SonerGönül you mean `.Where(line => !(line.StartsWith("//") || line.StartsWith("#")))`

Comment: They used to have something called the "C preprocessor" which did this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI Rahul's answer based on SonerGönül **is wrong**, the code has a bug and doesn't work.

To save anyone typing, here's a functioning/tested answer which just uses matching.

In relation to the question at hand, it appears there **is not** anything SPECIFICALLY built-in to .Net which "understands" typical comments in text. You just have to write it from scratch using matching like this...

```
// ExtensionsSystem.cs, your handy system-like extensions
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public static class ExtensionsSystem
    {
    public static List<string> CleanLines(this string stringFromFile)
        {
        List<string> result = new List<string>(
            stringFromFile
            .Split(new string[] { "\r","\n" },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            );

        result = result
            .Where(line => !(line.StartsWith("//")
                            || line.StartsWith("#")))
            .ToList();

        return result;
        }
    }
```

and then you'd

```
List<string> lines = controlFile.text.CleanLines();
foreach (string ln in lines) Debug.Log(ln);
```

Comment: How is this any different from the other two answers that were *already* given?

Answer (score 9):

You can try like this:

```
var t= Path.GetTempFileName();
var l= File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("//") || !l.StartsWith("#"));
File.WriteAllLines(t, l);
File.Delete(fileName);
File.Move(t, fileName);
```

So you can basically copy the contents of your original file into a temp file which does not have comments line. Then delete the file and move the temp file to original file.

Comment: Multi-line comments will cause trouble with this ^

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I mean, this only works with the types of comments shown in the example.  The question is *incredibly* localized, primarily because because there's a lot of assumptions being made about the content of the file being processed.  This answer is complete in every sense of the word, as based on the current amount of information given to us in the question.

Comment: This will remove `#region / #endregion` directives as well, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `l => !l.StartsWith("//") && !l.StartsWith("#")`?  Either that or `l => !(l.StartsWith("//") || l.StartsWith("#"))` A line can't start with both `//` and `#`.

Comment: just FYI darrel I already pointed out that typo in the comments above, ***its also why I put in an answer below***

Comment: I'd also maybe consider calling Trim() or TrimStart() on the line being checked to lop off any whitespace off the front of the line

Answer (score 5):

Hope that this will make sense:

```
 string[] comments = { "//", "'", "#" };
 var CommentFreeText = File.ReadLines("fileName Here")
                       .Where(X => !comments.Any(Y => X.StartsWith(Y)));
```

You can populate the `comments[]` with the comment symbols that you want to remove from the textFile. While reading the text it will eliminate all the lines that start with any of the comment symbols.

And you can write it back using:

```
File.WriteAllLines("path", CommentFreeText);
```